# Is that a way to make authorisation with header in R like in python?

Tags: python, r, api

I try to connect my r script to an API. 
I saw that we could do that in python so I try to do the same in R but it doesn't seem to work

I would like to do that

```
http_url="https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/search/q=author%3A%22Alexandre%20Gallenne%22%20title%3A%22A%20distance%20to%20the%20Large%20Magellanic%20Cloud%20that%20is%20precise%20to%20one%20per%20cent%22&sort=date%20desc%2C%20bibcode%20desc&p_=0"
r=requests.get(http_url,headers={'Authorization:' 'Bearer ' + 'token'})
```

but in r

i tried this 
(sorry i cant give you any exemple because my token is private )

```
require("httr")
require("jsonlite")
res_reques<-GET(url =   http_url,add_headers("Authorization",'Bearer',token))
text<-content(res_reques,"text")
res_reques
```

the réponse status is 200(that seems correct but i dont have any data, and that is not nomal because my quest have result(if you tape the http_url in broswer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you did not use `add_headers` properly? Without being able to test, I would suggest

```
add_headers(Authorization=paste("Bearer", token))
```

Also note that `text` should contain the result, not `res_reques` (the last line of your code).

Comment: I will try in might take time to test it, thank you very munch =)

Comment: Could you be more specific? Maybe include the output of `dput(res_reques)` in your question?

Comment: i can beacause of privacy but i shoud have one result before the body ligne, i'm tryng to do it in python to  compere